# Teacher gave Jenny her car keys? Who is "her" referring to?

Tags: grammar

> Teacher gave Jenny her car keys.

Are they the keys of the teacher or Jenny?

What part of grammar in English language is about my question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **The** teacher gave Jenny the car keys. Now we have no idea whose car keys they were :)

Comment: The relevant concept in grammar is **anaphora**.

Comment: No.  anaphora is not a grammar concept.  It is a rhetorical device of repeating a word or phrase at the start of a series of sentences, for example MLK repeating "I have a dream...".  Please don't answer in comments. It bypasses the quality control system of up and down voting.

Answer (score 6):

It is ambiguous. It is *impossible* to know.

With more context it might be clear.  For example if you know that the Teacher is a man,  or if you know that Jenny is five years old.

This question is about ambiguity in the *antecedent* of the *pronoun*.  It is easy to write sentences like this that are ambiguous in any language.